# Basic clothing showroom

Tags: themes

I'm experimenting with Wordpress setups, and I'm curious if I can make some sort of showroom advertising items for sale. Is there any how-to or documentation I can refer to?

Comment: Define "showroom"? Do you have any examples of sites that look like what you want to achieve or something?

Comment: A gallery, basically.

Comment: Look for premium WP themes or gallery themes and you'll be set.

Answer (score 1):

For the most basic implementation you can look for fitting theme and make use of [gallery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) functionality of WordPress.

More complex or functional implementation might be better accomplished with one of the ecommerce plugins.

Comment: It seems I've to pay to use `wp-ecommerce`'s gallery function. I'm not aware of any other ecommerce plugin.